# Изменения в ядре linux по версиям

Tags: linux, kernel, diff

Нужна сводка изменений в ядре linux по версиям. Где ее можно найти? В идеале на русском. В гугле не нашел

Comment: Changelog'и есть на https://www.kernel.org/

Comment: Да, но там только по основным версиям

Comment: А вам по каким надо? В любом случае репозиторий с исходниками содержит нужные данные...

Comment: http://www.opennet.ru/keywords/kernel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете посмотреть [тут](https://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxVersions)
Это конечно, не на русском но все же. И да... Прекрасно гуглится

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/160894)

Comment: А что мне тут указывать? Историю изменений всех версия ядра Linux?

Comment: Это шаблонный ответ из очереди проверок. Ссылки в ответах не приветствуется, ибо завтра они могут уже не открываться. можно оставить комментарий. если ответ черезчур общий - значит закрыть) чего няньчиться